# MySQL trigger before insert update column with new auto-increment id

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like to update a column in my table with the country code and the new `id` which is an auto-increment value.

```
BEGIN
SET new.key = concat(new.countryCode,new.id);
END
```

`countryCode` works fine, but the `id` is always blank. How can I achieve something like this? The `id` comes from an `autoincrement` column.

I know it's not working because it's generated after the insert. So how can I do something like this?

Comment: Why not just create a view that returns that concatenated value? There is no real need to store this.

Comment: I need the value to use elsewhere. I've only used 2 values here. There are many more that'll be concatenated.

Answer (score 5):

`AUTO_INCREMENT` column are only set *after* insert.

If you need to *access* that value, you can only in an `AFTER INSERT` trigger. However, you cannot *modify* a column value in an `AFTER UPDATE`  trigger...

In addition, you cannot perform an update on the table used in your `AFTER INSERT` trigger as (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-program-restrictions.html):

> Within a stored function or trigger, it is not permitted to modify a
>   table that is already being used (for reading or writing) by the
>   statement that invoked the function or trigger.

---

Here the only reasonable solution would be to create a stored procedure to update the table, adjusting the relevant columns in a transaction to "emulate" you atomic insert statement.

---

That being said, *in your particular case*, the `key` column is redundant as that column is just the concatenation of two other columns of the same row.

Given its name, aren't you looking for a way to create a compound key instead? Something like that:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl ADD UNIQUE KEY (countryCode, id);
```

Comment: If I change it too after, I get the error :`/* SQL Error (1362): Updating of NEW row is not allowed in after trigger */`. I using HeidiSql to do this.

Comment: @Norman As far as I know, there is no way of achieve what you are trying to to by using a trigger. I edited my answer to provide some alternative solutions.

Comment: @Norman The `ALTER TABLE..`  create a *new index* on you table preventing you from having *duplicate* values for `(countryCode, id)`. I only speculated that was what you were trying to achieve based on the name of your column `key`. Maybe you should redefine *what* you are trying to do, since at this point there seems to be no "easy" way of doing it with MySQL the way intended first.

Comment: Can you use select with the last inserted record and use an after insert trigger? So after a record is inserted, select the last inserted row, do the concatenation and update. Something like that possible?

Comment: `KEY` doesn't prevent duplicates, only `UNIQUE` does that.

Comment: @Jack Thank you for pointing that. It was a stupid typo forgetting the keyword `UNIQUE` :/