# #1054 - Unkown column ' ' in 'field list' while I have a Trigger

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I created my table in phpMyAdmin and when I was trying to enter some data to test out my trigger I get this:  `error #1054 - Unknown column 'durl' in 'field list'`. I am using phpMyAdmin to insert the data so I am not sure why i get this error as it is a field that is available.

If I delete the trigger then it loads no problem.

Here is the sql query that is generated when I click the edit button in the error message.

```
 INSERT INTO `herfeven_herfevents`.`evenement` 
(`id`, `title`, `start`, `end`, `allday`, `url`, `durl`, `shop`, `phonenum`, 
 `street`,`city`, `state`, `zipcode`, `description`) 
 VALUES (NULL, 'Tatuaje', '2014-03-21 11:00:00', '2014-03-21 17:00:00', 
 '', '', 'eventDetails.php?id=', 'Test', '6033435555', '120 Test Rd', 
 'Test', 'NH', '03820', 'Testing this out')
```

Here is the trigger

```
  CREATE TRIGGER urlUpdate BEFORE INSERT ON evenement 
    FOR EACH ROW
      SET NEW.url = CONCAT(durl, id)
```

I am using this database for my jQuery FullCalendar and I want the link to pull up the php page based on the event. So I am trying to merge the durl which I have set at default of eventDetails.php?id= and then when this is CONCAT with id it will make the appropriate link.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show the table layout.  Are you sure there is a column called `durl`?

Comment: is your ID an AUTO_INCREMENT column?

Comment: if it is, have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18400436/mysql-trigger-before-insert-update-column-with-new-auto-increment-id

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
CREATE TRIGGER urlUpdate BEFORE INSERT ON evenement 
    FOR EACH ROW
      SET NEW.url = CONCAT(NEW.durl, NEW.id)
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/767c34/1).